# Разбор XML-схемы

Tags: xml, wsdl, java, xsd

Добрый день.
Предо мной стоит задача - полный разбор схемы XML + импортированных  + включенных в неё.
Сама задача есть даже не разбор схемы, а получение типов элементов с полными взаимоотношениями. Для понимания сути задачи:
**schema.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:myprefix="http://myhost.ru/service/" xmlns:anprefix="http://anotherhost.ru/pub-service/" targetNamespace="http://myhost.ru/service/">
    <xs:import namespace="http://anotherhost.ru/pub-service/" schemaLocation="anotherhost_schema.xsd"/>

    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ServiceCode" type="anprefix:ServiceCodeType">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Код услуги</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="MessageClass" type="myprefix:MessageClassType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="MessageClassType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="REQUEST">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Запрос от потребителя к поставщику
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="RESPONSE">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Ответ поставщика потребителю</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

**anotherhost_schema.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:anprefix="http://anotherhost.ru/pub-service/" targetNamespace="http://anotherhost.ru/pub-service/">
    <xs:simpleType name="ServiceCodeType">
        <restriction base="xs:string">
        </restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Пример не очень сложный, реальная задача намного объёмней. К чему это я, необходимо разобрать схему и создать её внутреннее представление (для генератора формы и обработчика запросов), например, таким образом:

```
{
"ServiceCode": {string, String.class, "Код услуги"},
"MessageClass": {string, {"REQUEST":"Запрос от потребителя к поставщику","RESPONSE":"Ответ поставщика потребителю"}, ""}
}
```

Или же в другом, но податливом для разбора виде. Есть ли такая библиотека? Даже если она не будет open-source. Решение с моей стороны - не скажу что хорошее. Оно кривое и попытка к рекурсии. Проход по списку элементов не буду выкладывать, но разбор попавшегося элемента код [на pastebin](http://pastebin.com/YY47Cd3A).

И для лучшего восприятия диаграмка на эту функцию:
[Диаграмма для приведённого кода](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG88o.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А [JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding) это разве не то что вы пытаетесь самопально реализовать?

Почитайте [JAXB туториалы](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnazg.html), в частности, [JAXB compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbah.html#bnbal), который и выдает на основании схемы готовую иерархию Java классов соответствующих заданной схеме.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию про JAXB. В частности, про туториалы, но JAXB Compilier преследует другую цель - он создаёт иерархию классов, а передо мной стоит цель разбирать это на лету.

Comment: @Barmaley, просмотрел, там есть описание того, что необходимо, но вот конретику найти не получается. Если Вам не трудно, пожалуйста, укажите на место, где существует практическая часть для того теоретического материала, который Вы предоставили. Спасибо