# Динамическое подключение и использование java-классов

Tags: xml, jaxb, java, xsd

Продолжение [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/151770/java-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-xml-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B). Узнал и разобрался как XJC генерирует классы для типов. Отсюда вопрос - как динамически подключать и использовать их?

Comment: интересно, я один не понял вопрос?

Comment: @Gorets, что именно не понятно? Если необходимо я могу описать подробнее.

Comment: Вопрос о кодогенерации в run-time?

Comment: @Nofate, вопрос о использовании и подключении сегнерированных внешней программой классов во время работы

Comment: @stck,

> сегнерированных внешней программой  

Вы хотите подключить в одно приложение класс, созданный в другом?

Comment: одно объяснение лучше другого =) может давай на примере?))

Comment: @teanЫЧ, не совсем. Одно приложение генерирует java-файлы с классами (не моё, а копилятор xjc, идущий вместе с JAXB). А в моём приложении, необходимо их динамически подгружать и использовать.
@Gorets, есть файл (схема XML) с указанием типов. Этот файл идёт параметром компилятора XJC. XJC разбирает его, затем из своей сериализации генерирует классы в *.java по именам типов. Мне их надо подключить, использовать и удалить без следов, дабы каждый раз пользоваться заново-сгенерированными классами, так как требования и указания в них постоянно меняются (где-то 1 раз в 3 дня).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я вопрос понял. Вопрос сложный. По сути речь идет о том, чтобы в рантайме скомпилировать исходники и прицепить к аппе - фактически состоит из 2-х частей:

1. Как подключить класс в рантайме
2. Как скомпилировать класс в рантайме

Если первый решается загрузчиком класса - конструкцией типа `Class.forName()` в связке с `ClassLoader`, то второй вопрос сложнее, но при использовании Java >= 6 это решаемо:

```
String fileToCompile = "MyClass.java"; 
JavaCompiler compiler = javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler(); 
int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);
```

Если Java < 6 то есть только недокументированные возможности (я уже забыл какие).

Comment: @Barmaley, спасибо. Второй день Вы меня выручаете. Только 1 единственный вопрос - после того как мы воспользуемся компилятором исходного кода(JavaCompilier) будут оставаться лишние файлы? Или указания? Или что-нибудь из этого рода.

Comment: @stck да хз... управляйте ключами компилятора и пихайте вывод в какой-нить каталог, а компилятору скажите что временный каталог там-то. По идее весь мусор после компилятора останется во временном каталоге, а ваши классы лягут в другой каталог